# What's a more idiomatic Ruby way of writing this?

Tags: ruby, syntax, idioms

```
  if params[:parent_type] == "Order"
    parent_id = nil
  else
    parent_id = params[:parent_id]
  end
```

Would a Ruby person laugh at me for writing it this way? It doesn't seem particularly concise like some Ruby code I've seen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That looks perfectly reasonable to me. You could move the assignment in front of the if ( `parent_id = if params...`) or use the ternary, but I don't think the result would look better.

If parent_id is nil or undefined before that line you can simply write:

```
parent_id = params[:parent_id] unless params[:parent_type] == "Order"
```

Comment: awesome... this is the ruby way to do things, assignment goes in front. this is the reason "unless" was created so we can have the same convention inversely.

Answer (score 7):

Nothing really wrong with it as-is, but can be made more concise:

```
parent_id = (params[:parent_type] == "Order") ? nil : params[:parent_id]
```

Alternatively:

```
parent_id = if (params[:parent_type] == "Order")
    nil
else
    params[:parent_id]
end
```

Comment: There's a typo there. The ">" should be a "?"

Comment: I really like the second option. Makes it clear that both options ultimately assign value to parent_id.

Comment: The ternary form always assigns a value, unlike the "x = y unless z" form, which leaves x alone if x is already assigned (as does the if-else). So if you want a one-liner that replicates the if-else form, go with the ternary.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's fine the way it is. I'm a Ruby person, and I wouldn't laugh at you for writing it that way. It's clear what the code does and there's no real code duplication, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

I like:

```
parent_id = (params[:parent_type] == "Order" ? nil : params[:parent_id])
```

Answer (score 1):

One more variation:

```
parent_id = (params[:parent_type] == "Order") && params[:parent_id]
```

Comment: not a very expressive way.. quite confusing actually the fact that the logical operator do not only return booleans...

Answer (score 0):

We can use Ruby ternary operator. Something like it:

```
parent_id = params[:parent_type] == "Order" ? nil : params[:parent_id]
```

If `parent_id` is set with `nil` value, we can write an unless syntax:

```
parent_id = params[:parent_id] unless params[:parent_type] == "Order"
```

Or write a simple Ruby if-else in a different way you did it:

```
parent_id = if (params[:parent_type] == "Order")
  nil
else
  params[:parent_id]
end
```

For more [**Idiomatic Ruby**](https://medium.com/the-renaissance-developer/idiomatic-ruby-1b5fa1445098) way to code, I found an [**awesome article**](https://medium.com/the-renaissance-developer/idiomatic-ruby-1b5fa1445098) about that.